# r rticle package stopped compiling after recent updates

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, r-package

I have just installed R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt), under RStudio 2022.07.2 (Build 576), and the rticle package (v 0.24). At this moment, these are the most recent versions of the three systems.

I first tried to compile the basic MDPI template (\New File\R MarkDown\From Template\MDPI Journal Article) and got the following message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \gather already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

Erro: LaTeX failed to compile Novo.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Novo.log for more info.
```

I tried also another file that I was normally compiling a couple of days ago, and got the same message.

Any help or clue of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I'd guess this is a problem with your LaTeX packages.  I don't get that error when I try that example, so I can't say exactly where, but you should have a `.log` file left in the directory after the error.  Somewhere near the end of that file it will give some context for the error message.  You may need to update one of them (or roll back an update that `rticles` isn't compatible with).  It can be hard to read those logs, so if you have trouble, edit the last part of it (say 20 or 30 lines leading up to the error message) into your question.

Comment: I get the same error when compiling the MDPI template.tex file on a fully updated TexLive 2022 installation. I didn't get this error before updating, so it must be an update to some package that causes this...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [r rticle package stopped compiling after recent updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74889936/r-rticle-package-stopped-compiling-after-recent-updates)

Comment: This might also help: https://github.com/latex-lineno/lineno/issues/5